How to merge Redis search objects
I need to iterate over index list and perform Redis search and need to combine all the result objects into one, I wrote the below code which is not working.
import redis

redis_conn = redis.Redis(host=<redis_host>, port=<redis_port>, db=0)
query = "query"
index_lst = ["index1", "index2", "index3"]

results = []
for index in index_lst:
    search_result = redis_conn.ft(index).search(query)
    results.extend(search_result)

I know we can use results.extend(search_result.docs) instead of results.extend(search_result) to fix the issue but need to know if its possible to merge all the result objects into one.

Suppose search_result.docs is [{'id': '1', 'json': '{"a":1, "b":2}'}, {'id': '2', 'json': '{"a":2, "c":3}'}]. How would "merged into one object" look like?
